# is or was named

Tags: tense

if I want to express that a person's name is John Meyer? Which of the following is correct?

> He **is** / **was** named John Meyer.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: How about *"His name is John Meyer."*?

Answer (score 0):

To an extent it depends upon the context.

In real life contexts, while John Mayer is still alive, you would use **He is John Mayer**. After John Mayer has died, you would use **He was John Mayer**.

The exact structure of **He is John Mayer** is rather uncommon, though - you'd more often use something like **His name is John Mayer**.

The exception is in a past-tense narrative. In this sense, even if you're writing about people who are still alive at the time of the narrative or even at the time of writing, you would use the past tense form **was**.

Comment: If he is still alive, should I use "He is named John Meyer" or "He was named John Meyer"?

Comment: @Apollyon In the exact sentence you propose, you would only use the past tense for somebody still alive if they've changed their name and you are referring to the previous name. ("He was John Mayer. Now he is John Smith.") If you're referring to their current name, you use the present tense. (But in a different sentence construction that's not the case: "A man robbed the store." "Who was he?" "He was John Mayer." Although normally the question would be "Who was it?" and the answer would be just "John Mayer," if any tense were to be used it would be the past tense.)

Comment: @JasonBassford your answer doesn't include what OP is asking, specifically the tense of be (is/was) with "named" not on its own.

Comment: @eques Just add "named" to the first part of my comment. "He *was* named John Mayer. Now he *is* named John Smith." (And he's still alive.) The parenthetical part of my comment was something additional, and still relevant to *is* or *was* and identity, even if "named" wasn't part of it. That's why it was in parentheses.

Comment: @JasonBassford it should be folded into your main response -- comments are not considered "permanent". And secondly it is not obvious that with/without named function identically. In fact there are unlikely circumstances where they would not be used in the same cases -- e.g. when you are referring the event itself when someone received a name then "He was named" might be used even though he is still alive

Comment: @eques I haven't answered anything. (I merely provided a comment underneath somebody else's answer.) I'm quite fine with the comment being deleted—as with all of the comments here. If you want to provide permanent commentary, then you should provide an answer . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford my mistake -- didn't notice you weren't the original answerer.

Answer (score 0):

if John Meyer is alive you should use

> he is named John Meyer. `Passive voice`

or

> he is John Meyer. `Active voice`

if John Meyer is not alive now you should use

> he was named John Meyer. `Passive voice`

or

> he was John Meyer. `Active voice`

Comment: While the labels of passive are correct, it would be important to note that the "Active" labeled sentences are not the active versions of the passive ones since they use a different verb construction.

Answer (score 0):

**named** can refer to the act of naming:

> He is | was named John Meyer, after his grandfather.

If you're just telling someone his name:

> Who's that dude going wild with the karaoke?
>   --His name is John Meyer.

If someone phones asking to speak to your colleague, who is not there, and you take a message, you can say to your colleague upon their return:

> A man named John Meyer called for you.

or

> A "John Meyer" called for you.

or

> A man called for you. He said his name was John Meyer. There was loud singing in the background so I didn't catch his phone number. Sorry.

Comment: If the naming act took place when he was born, and his name is still John Meyer, can we use "He is named John Meyer"? I am comparing "be named" and "be called" in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

Neither. His name is. Start a new sentence.
You should also cooler a picture of John if you can. Any kind of informal mention is ride. From my experience.

Comment: I’m not sure that ‘he is named’ is necessarily incorrect. Could you provide a reference for your assertion? Additionally, I’m really not sure what you’re trying to say in the last three. You could [edit] your answer to improve it.